# Cannot install mysql connector/net. Showing error "failed to install performance counters. (-2147024894)"

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I am unable to install the mysql connector as it shows the error message "failed to install performance counters. (-2147024894)". Please provide a step by step guide if registry tools are involved.

I tried everything but cannot solve it.

[image]